# Slackware su man pages does not mention /etc/suauth, what reason?

Tags: su, slackware

I've been reading the man pages before I start restricting su access to certain users (I'd like to not rely on sudo if possible). There is no /etc/suauth file so I was going to create my own and wanted to check the correct way to do it (rather than just creating the file). I don't want to lock myself out.

```
man suauth
```

tells me how to do it
however

```
man su
```

does not mention the /etc/suauth file at all though mentions a lot about the /etc/login.defs

Before I experiment (create a user outside of wheel, login and test su , and then create  /etc/suauth banning that user from becoming root and retrying) is there an explanation for this inconsistency?

Using Slackware 14.1 by the way...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just checked the source and it seems /etc/suauth checking is an extension (linux only? not the bsd way) so perhaps is not in the original man page. /etc/suauth is hard coded into the suauth.c file in the shadow package. The function it defines is called by su if pam is not in use...I think. I will check further and edit my own question when I have a clear answer/clarification.